# Splitting out semicolon separated values into individual child elements (XML)

Tags: xml, xslt

We have some XML which contains many elements, one of which contains semicolon separated values. However we want each of those values inserted into a new child element.

For example. Currently the XML looks like this: `<value>one;two;three</value>`

But I need:

```
<value>
<item>one</item>
<item>two</item>
<item>three</item>
</value>
```

I imagine some kind of transform is required?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
<xsl:template name="extract-item">
  <xsl:param name="items" />
  <xsl:if test="$items != ''">
    <item>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($items, ';')" />
    </item>
    <xsl:call-template name="extract-item">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="substring-after($items, ';')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
  <value>
    <xsl:call-template name="extract-item">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="concat(., ';')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Erlock's answer is the right approach in XSLT.

That said, if the only thing you need to do is turn all the semicolons-separated items into elements, you could also do it with a *nix command like:

```
sed -e 's/<value>/<value><item>/g' 
    -e 's/<\value>/<\/item><\/value>/g'
    -e 's/;/<\/item><item>/g' myfile.xml
```

This assumes there are no other semicolons floating around, and there are no XML comments, PIs, or CDATA sections to worry about. If you're not sure it's that simple, XSLT is the way to go.